# how to reset to browser default css?

Tags: css

I'm using joomla template in which various stylesheet files are there for page layout. I'm demonstrating the brief way here:

**style1.css**

```
#header ul.menu li a{ background-color: red; }
```

**style2.css**

```
#header ul.menu li a{ color: blue; }
```

**style3.css**

```
ul.menu li a:hover{ background-color: gray; }
```

**style4.css**

```
ul li a:active{ background-color: green; }
```

**style5.css**

```
ul.menu { list-style: none;}
ul.menu li{display: inline;}
ul li a{float: left; display: block;}
```

What's the best way to reset default styles of `#header` menu?

I could reset the css as my own staying at **style1.css** as followings placing `!important` if needed:

```
#header ul.menu{list-style: none;}
#header ul.menu li{display: inline-block;}
#header ul.menu li a{color: black; background-color: none;}
#header ul.menu li a:hover{color: black; background-color: none;}
#header ul.menu li a:active{color: black; background-color: none;}
```

But for this I have see first what styles are applied in that menu and then set my own styles.

But I'm looking for the css rules that whatever the styles are applied in that menu I could reset to its browser defaults. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: load the css file at the bottom which you want to apply...

Comment: @DipeshParmar I've done that way but I need to check what styles are applied then  reset. Please re-read last paragraph.

Comment: Why don't you set the value in each? Or you might use `if else` block. To make sure the current css is the one you want it to be.

Comment: There are several existing questions about resetting to browser defaults (a bit difficult to find, admittedly). The bottom line is that you can’t get browser default for a property for an element except by simply *not setting the property at all* in any rule that matches the element.

Answer (score 0):

two ways with javascript

1. change the className (you will have to replace "#header" with ".header")
2. change the stylesheet being used